# How get spotify track uri?

Tags: javascript, html, tracking, spotify

I have a list of concerts in Spotify and each concert is generating list of tracks. I'm doing some additional work and modifying my code and i need songs(track) ids which i can dynamically use. can anyone help me that how can i get track id? I'm using "song Kick" API. please help anyone.

```
        playlist_Tracks[i];
```

this line brings all the names of top tracks but how to bring Uri/id of these songs

Or anyone know how to convert track name into track id( Spotify URI).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming playlistTracks[i] is the standard Track object from the API, the URI can be accessed with playlistTracks[i].data.uri

See the JS Docs here for more info: https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/4f52ebf870.html

Comment: Link is now dead.